# Attribute Set & Attributes Best Practices

Tags: attributes, attribute-set

So I have a fashion online store, and I'm currently faced with two options when planning the content structure and the attribute set. Lets say I have a size attribute, that have different options depending on the item. So for examlpe for Jeans it's 32/34/36 etc.., while for boxers for example it's Large/Medium/Small. The question is, should I:

- Create one single size attribute, with all the possible values (32/34/36/Small/Large/Medium etc..), all under the *General* attribute set
- Create a separate size attribute for each category, so for Jeans I'll create a Size attribute for the possible values, and for Boxers I'll create another size attributes with the possible values. And then I'll create an attribute set called Jeans, and another called Boxer.

So far it makes more sense for me to go for the first option, i mean there is no  drawbacks I could think of. What do you guys suggest, is there any reason to go for the second option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first option is better as all are size values and one attribute value will be assigned to one category.

If you have multiple attributes which depend on the different kind product type like shirt,sunglass,watch then only create an attribute set.